# Create iPhone webapp without mac

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, web-applications

I am going to create a web app that will be distributed for Android, iPhone and maybe WP.

I do not have a Mac, so how do I make a webapp for iPhone, the only thing I need is a webview with no zoom or anything else, that opens a specific site(Should be really easy?).

I can easily create it for Android and WP with Windows, but how can i do it for iPhone. I have been looking at some frameworks but what do you guys reccommend. I am looking for something 100% free that works out of the box and with no ads or other stuff.

A little bonus question. Is jQuerymobile recommendable to use for WebApps, or should I stick to another framework? Witch?

Comment: Have a look here http://line25.com/tutorials/design-and-code-a-cool-iphone-app-website-in-html5

Comment: @DmitryBoyko I don't think your tutorial is relevant to OP's question.

Comment: http://gigaom.com/apple/how-to-create-an-iphone-web-app/ is great. Justed it for a project a while ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well what you want, you just need to display a webpage in a web view without use hardware stuff on the iPhone, isn't it ? So why don't you develop the website/webapp you want, hosts it on a server and give the link for the iPhone on your website that describe your web app ? I purpose that for you because there are some stuff that create an immersion in which the user believe that's an app and not a website :
in the HTML source code, just add the following :

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320;" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/default.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/homescreen.png"/>
```

With this, and after you put the website in bookmark on the springboard (wall of app), when you launch the website like any other app (with the specific icon and splash screen you want), you don't have the Safari Mobile interface and then it's like you have a real application. Plus, with HTML5 caching you can use the website offline.

To develop specific part of your website, jQuery and jQuery Mobile will give you many help.

Comment: I need to publish it. I could easily create it on a Mac but i dont have access to one.

Comment: Oh ok, so indeed you need a Mac, a developer account and buy the Apple Developer Program, so without a Mac, it's impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, gonna look into buying a MBP then. Since i am planning to start my own company.

Comment: Good luck to start your own company

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to build a web app rather than a native app, then the process is pretty straightforward: create a web app. That's really it. There's nothing different/special you need to do for iPhone vis-a-vis Android when it comes to web apps because they both use WebKit under the hood.

As far as frameworks, there are several options. Personally, I use (and recommend) [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com), however there are plenty of other options available depending on your needs. If what you're building is relatively simple you may not need a framework at all - just a tutorial on responsive design like [this one from Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EasyStepsToAMobilefriendlyResponsiveDesignWithAnEmbeddedYouTubeVideoAndAFluidResize.aspx)

HTH

Comment: I think he wants to publish it to the App Store.

Comment: Additionally you should consider getting an iPhone/iPod Touch to do on-device testing.

Comment: @Louis There doesn't seem to be any indication of that in the question.

Comment: Sorry yes i want to publish it, so i need to wrap it into a webview on an iPhone.

Comment: Ah, well that being the case then I'm afraid that what you're asking is not possible. You will need a Mac to compile, publish, and distribute the app.